# Creating a custom post type plugin - wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to create a custom type plugin. And I am not really sure what is wrong with my code since there is no errors but the plugin is not working even tho I already activate it.

```
defined( 'ABSPATH' ) or die( 'No script kiddies please!' ); // copied in codex 

class LouisPlugin
{
    
    function __contruct() {
        add_action ('init',array($this, 'custom_post_type'));

    }
    
    function activate(){
        
    }
    
    function deactivate(){
        
    }
    
    function unsintall(){
        
    }
    
    function custom_post_type(){
        register_post_type('job_list',['public' => true, 'label'=>'job_list']);
    }
        

    
}

if (class_exists('LouisPlugin')){
    $louisPlugin = new LouisPlugin();
}


register_activation_hook( __FILE__, array($louisPlugin, 'activate' ) );

register_deactivation_hook(__FILE__, array($louisPlugin,'deactivate'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please check your code

```
function __contruct() {
        add_action ('init',array($this, 'custom_post_type'));

    }
```

the `__construct` method name was incorrect I think this can be one reason

```
function __construct() {
    add_action ('init',array($this, 'custom_post_type'));
}
```